# show data in dropdownlist from sqlserver in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three dropdownlist the code below

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ForumTitleList" runat="server"

                        AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ForumSubTitleList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                        >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ForumSubjectTitleList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                       >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and the code behind is

```
enter code here 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Auzine.Forums
{
    public partial class ForumIT : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        ConfigurationFuntion();

        DropForumTitle();
        DropForumSubTitle();
        DropForumSubjectTitle();
    }


protected void DropForumTitle()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuzineConnection"].ConnectionString;

        string selectSQL = "select DISTINCT ForumTitlesID,ForumTitles from ForumTtitle";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {

            ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = "Select";
            newItem.Value = "0";
            ForumTitleList.Items.Add(newItem);
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListItem newItem1 = new ListItem();
                newItem1.Text = reader["ForumTitles"].ToString();
                newItem1.Value = reader["ForumTitlesID"].ToString();
                ForumTitleList.Items.Add(newItem1);



            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        //////////////////

    }
}
protected void DropForumSubjectTitle()
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       // ForumSubjectTitleList.Items.Clear();
        string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuzineConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);

        con.Open();



        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT ForumSubjectTitle from ForumSubject where ForumSubTitlesID='" + ForumSubTitleList.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        // ForumTitleList.Items.Clear();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ForumSubjectTitleList.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());


        }

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();



    }

}

protected void DropForumSubTitle()
{


    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ForumSubTitleList.Items.Clear();
        string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuzineConnection"].ConnectionString;
        string selectSQL = "select DISTINCT ForumTitlesID,ForumSubTitles from ForumSubtitle where ForumTitlesID='" + ForumTitleList.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ";
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {

            ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = "Select";
            newItem.Value = "0";
            ForumSubTitleList.Items.Add(newItem);
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListItem newItem1 = new ListItem();
                newItem1.Text = reader["ForumSubTitles"].ToString();
                newItem1.Value = reader["ForumTitlesID"].ToString();
                ForumSubTitleList.Items.Add(newItem1);



            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        //////////////////

    }
    }
}
```

DropForumTitle() for dropdown1(ForumTitleList) list one is working fine and then for dropdown2(ForumSubTitleList) I want to search according to the selected value of dropdown1(ForumTitleList) and when do that as i write the code for dropdown1(ForumTitleList) then it is not showing any thing but when change the code from if (!Page.IsPostBack) to if (Page.IsPostBack) then it shows but the selected index goes aoutomatically to 0... It display right but when select any option from dropdown2(ForumSubTitleList) then it goes to selected index 0 bydefault and for this error the dropdown3(ForumSubjectTitleList) can recieve the selected item valu and does not shows subjectlist from database ... each of dropdown list are connected with an ID if dropdown displays any thing then second dropdown = to selected value of dropdown 1 and same as dropdown3 = to the selected valu of dropdown2

but I getting error with bothe dropdown2 and dropdown3

In short:

1-dropdown2 does not stay to the value I selected: let suppose in the LIst A, b, C, and D. when I click on A it posrback and the selected value is again A;

2- dropdown3 can not access the selected value of dropdown2 therefore it is not showing anything...

Answer (score 1):

In every post-back you're doing two things with each drop-down list:

1. Re-populate it with data
2. Populate the next one

That first step is what's getting rid of your selected value.  It can't retain the selected value when you clear the values and add new ones.

You need to separate these actions.  For starters, let's assume you have `DropDownList1` and its selection should drive `DropDownList2`.  Then `Page_Load` should only be populating `DropDownList1` and only when it's not a post-back.  Something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        PopulateDropDownList1();
}
```

To populate `DropDownList2`, you would respond to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `DropDownList1`.  Something like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    PopulateDropDownList2(value);
}
```

Keep in mind that `Page_Load` gets calls on *every* load of the page, even post-backs, and it's called *before* events like `SelectedIndexChanged`.  So if you re-populate your parent list in `Page_Load` then there will no longer be a selected value in `SelectedIndexChanged`.

With the above scenario, the order of events would be:

1. User loads the page.
2. `Page_Load` executes.
3. It's not a post-back, so `DropDownList1` gets populated with values.
4. User selects a value in `DropDownList1` and triggers a post-back.
5. `Page_Load` executes.
6. It *is* a post-back, so `Page_Load` doesn't do anything.
7. `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` executes.
8. `DropDownList2` gets populated with values.

At this point the user can now see what they selected in `DropDownList1` and the new values in `DropDownList2`.  Extending this to a third `DropDownList` is the same pattern.  You'd create a `DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged` which does the same thing as `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`, but with the next cascading list.

Comment: Thanks Sir David but still I am getting error the one error is dropdown2 is again select the top value and therefore the 3rd one can not proceed as it should be

Comment: @SyedAzy: Can you update your question to show your current code which produces this behavior?  If the selection of the list is being reset on post-back then you're probably still re-populating the list on post-back.

Comment: sir thank you so much all of you to provide me instant help....the problem is solved now , thank you so much,thank you so much ,thank you so much,thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to populate:

Method

```
private void Bind()
{

    var dt = YourFunctionReturningDataTable(); 
    //Assuming your table has two columns Id,Name

    dropdownlist1.datasource = dt;
    dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "Name";
    dropdownlist1.DataValueField="Id";
    dropdownlist1.DataBind();
    dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---","-1"));
}

private void Page_Load()
{


  if(!IsPostback)
  {
  Bind();   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Amit Ranjan but still I am getting error the one error is dropdown2 is again select the top value and therefore the 3rd one can not proceed as it should be

Comment: sir thank you so much all of you to provide me instant help....the problem is solved now , thank you so much,thank you so much ,thank you so much,thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best way to show all genre name in dropdown list. I used EDMX and LINQ query.

```
 ASPX:
===============
<asp:DropDownList ID="GenreList" runat="server" SelectMethod="GenreList_GetData" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    C#:
    ============
     public IEnumerable<Genre> GenreList_GetData()
        {
            using(PlanetWroxEntities myEntities= new PlanetWroxEntities())
            {
                return (from genre in myEntities.Genres
                        orderby genre.SortOrder
                        select genre).ToList();
            }
        }
```